# Como enviar um ArrayList<Object> para WebService SOAP

Tags: java, android, soap

Boa Tarde

Supondo que eu tenha as seguintes classes Pedido e Item em Java:

```
public class Pedido implements KvmSerializable, Serializable {

private String numero;
private ArrayList<Item> itens;

public String getNumero(){
    return numero;
}

public void setNumero(String numero){
    this.numero = numero;
}

public ArrayList<Item> getItens(){
    return itens;
}

public void setItens(ArrayList<Item> itens){
    this.itens = itens;
}

public Pedido(){

}
}
```

---

```
public class Item implements KvmSerializable, Serializable {

private String codigo;
private double valor;

public String getCodigo(){
    return codigo;
}

public void setCodigo(String codigo){
    this.codigo = codigo;
}


public double getValor(){
    return valor;
}

public void setValor(double valor){
    this.valor = valor;
}

public Item(){

}
}
```

Qual o procedimento para enviar um objeto Pedido com vários itens para um WebService que utilize a tecnologia SOAP, utilizando a biblioteca KSOAP2 via Android?

Consigo fazer a requisição normalmente com objetos que não envolvam Arrays, mas quando isso ocorre recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize:

Desde já, agradeço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa Tarde

Consegui resolver o meu problema. Não sei ao certo porque a biblioteca KSOAP2 age dessa forma, mas de jeito nenhum eu consegui serializar um array de forma automática conforme faço com atributos de tipos primitivos.

A solução que eu encontrei foi passar a lista como um parâmetro separado e adicionar ao objeto no momento de montar a requisição. Seguindo o exemplo da classe acima, a solução seria:

```
private final String NAMESPACE = "SEU_NAMESPACE";    

public void SeuMetodo(Pedido pedido, ArrayList<Item> itens) {
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "SeuMetodo");
    SoapObject ped = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "pedido");
    SoapObject arrayItens = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "Itens");

    for (Item item : itens){
        arrayItens.addProperty("Item", item);
    }

    ped.addProperty("numero", pedido.getNumero());
    ped.addProperty("Itens", arrayItens);

    request.addProperty("pedido", ped);

    try {
        //PROCEDIMENTOS DE ENVIO DA REQUISIÇÃO E RECEBIMENTO DA RESPOSTA
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Espero ter conseguido ser claro, se mais alguém tiver esse problema e precisar de ajuda estou à disposição.

Answer (score 0):

troque `public class Pedido {` por `public class Pedido implements Serializable {`

e

`public class Item {` por `public class Item implements Serializable {`

Se suas classes não forem serializadas não poderão ser enviadas ao backend, isso já deverá resolver o problema :D

Comment: Já estou implementando a interface Serializable nas classes, acabei esquecendo de colocar no código aqui, vou atualizar. Porém continuo com o mesmo problema, não consigo serializar um Array de objetos.

Comment: O erro continua o mesmo ? ou mudou ?

Comment: Continua o mesmo, eu consigo serializar tanto o objeto Pedido quando o objeto Item, desde que separadamente. Meu problema está em serializar um objeto Pedido com um ou mais Itens dentro dele.